# main storyboard with custom rootVievController doesn't call vc's init

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to iOS programming, so don't be rude)
I create my view controller and connected it to Main.storyboard in appDelegate. It works.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    TestViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TestViewController"];
    [self.window setRootViewController:vc];

    return YES;
}
```

In TestViewController.m in init put some data to NSArray, but it doesn't execute.

```
- (instancetype) init {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    self = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SMKQuizViewController"]; ...
```

I tried just init and initWithNib, but both don't work.
What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load a ViewController from storyboard init will not get called instead you can put your code in

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.yourArray = ["ABCD","EFGH"] //initialize ur array
}
```

And if you are hell bent on writing init :) You can use

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.yourArray = ["ABCD","EFGH"] //initialize ur array
}
```

**EDIT:**

init in Objective-C

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        //initialize your array here :)
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: thank) how can i write second option with required init in objective-c? Is it possible? Or required is just stuff from Swift?

Comment: @vladimir-samoilenko : Please have a look at the updated answer :)

Comment: @vladimir-samoilenko : Always welcome :) Please consider accepting the answer if the answer helped u :)